# Unable to query data using Postman

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, postman

I've set a Node.js server and trying to query data (from MySQL) through Postman. `Select * from table` works perfectly fine but when I read the input through `req.body.foo` Node.js throws me an error:

> Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Server.js:

```
var app = require('express')(); // Express App include
var http = require('http').Server(app); // http server
var mysql = require('mysql'); // Mysql include 
var bodyParser = require("body-parser"); // Body parser for fetch posted data
var connection = mysql.createConnection({ // Mysql Connection
host : 'localhost',
user : 'root',
password : 'mayur',
database : 'mayur',
});

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/',function(req,res){

connection.query("SELECT * from login where username= ?? ", req.body.username ,function(err, rows, fields){
    if(rows.length != 0){
        res.json(rows);

    }else{
        var data = 'No users Found..';
        res.json(data);
    }
});
});

 app.listen(3030);
```

Comment: can you share your postman part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to select **x-www-form-urlencoded** in the postman since you are using `req.body.username` to access the `username`.

[image]

Set Key to **username** and Value to a valid value and everything should work fine.

Comment: It must be because you have selected GET request. Change it to a POST request and change the `app.get('/',function(req,res)` to `app.post('/',function(req,res)`

Comment: Now localhost:3030 says `Cannot GET /`

Comment: Try changing  `if(rows.length != 0)` to  `if(rows)`

Comment: Oh cool, this works , but now it says "No users found" even when there are users in the table. And no matter whatever I enter in the Key field it shows the same output

Comment: try changing 
`connection.query("SELECT * from login where username= ? ", req.body.username ,function(err, rows, fields)` 
to 
`connection.query("SELECT * from login where username= ? ", [req.body.username] ,function(err, rows, fields)`

Comment: changing '??' to '?' worked , this is absurd. I wonder whats the difference between double question marks and single ?

Comment: Thanks :) I was trying to google '?' but couldn't come up with valid resources

Comment: ?? is the placeholders for identifiers. You can find more details  https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#escaping-query-identifiers.

? is the placeholders for values. You can find more details at https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#escaping-query-values